# How do you configure .inputrc so ALT+UP has the effect of cd 

Tags: bash, readline

It should be possible to do that by having ALT+UP generate consecutive keyboard input equivalent to <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> by means of a macro definition.  But can't figure out how exactly to do it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To do literally what you're asking, put the following line in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e\e[A": "cd ..\n"
```

Here `\e\e[A` is byte sequence that your terminal sends when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> (`\e` is parsed as the escape character), some terminals might send `\e[1;3A~` or some other sequence instead. To find out what sequence your terminal sends, run `cat` and press the key (escape will display as `^[`).

In bash, you can in principle bind a key to shell code, so in theory this should work:

```
bind -x '"\e\e[A":cd ..'
```

However as of bash 4.2 [it doesn't work due to a hard-to-fix implementation bug](http://old.nabble.com/bash_execute_unix_command%3A-cannot-find-keymap-for-command-td29071752.html). Zsh expert [Stéphane Chazelas](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.unix.shell/PjuDehtFhM8/XYpMo1TZm04J) has a workaround:

```
bind -x '"\201":cd ..'
bind '"\e\e[A":"\201"'
```

The effect is somewhat confusing because the prompt isn't redrawn.

In bash ≥4, add `shopt -s autocd` to your `~/.bashrc`. Then you can change to the parent directory (or any directory) by entering just `..`, without having to type the `cd` command.

Comment: This looks like a super-high quality answer, but for some reason it is not working in a Git Bash shell on Windows.  (Haven't pulled out my Air to test there though yet...)  Are you aware of any gotchas that uniquely affect Cygwin?

Comment: (I should have mentioned that it closes the terminal window.)

Comment: @iconoclast What terminal are you running bash in? I wouldn't be surprised if the default Windows terminal doesn't send a usable character sequence for `Alt+Up`. I recommend Mintty, or at least Console2, see [How do you configure a Windows machine for a Linux user?](http://superuser.com/questions/282397/how-do-you-configure-a-windows-machine-for-a-linux-user/282762#282762)

Comment: AFAIK the bash shell that comes with Git for Windows is just an old version of Cygwin, and runs a bourne shell inside of a cmd.exe window.  If any of the terminals you recommend are portable, I can easily try them out before trying to get permission to install.  (Oh! the joys of working in a Windows shop!)

Comment: for some reason SE removed "@Gilles:" from the beginning of my comments.  WTF!?

Comment: @iconoclast I think both Console2 and Mintty are portable. For Console2, unpack the zip and run it. For Mintty, you need `mintty.exe` plus the Cygwin dll either in the same directory or elsewhere on the `%PATH%`. Regarding the stripping of `@Gilles`: [Eeeeek - what happened to my @ salutation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/97099#97099)

Comment: Oh boy! [I get to be the canonical user confused by this useless feature!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation#97099)  The UX designer for Stack Exchange should be whipped with a wet noodle, and then they should display a notification the first few times they do this to someone. (Occasional users will forget if there's a big gap between uses.)

Comment: @iconoclast I think the founder and then lead developer (not a UX person) forced this feature through. Don't blame the UX designer for this.

Comment: okay, then the UX designer should whip the founder and lead developer for it.